# How to assign range from ActiveCell for future reference (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign the ActiveCell to a variable in order to use it later. It gives me a timeout error.

Code is below, but generally I haven't figured out how to assign a range to a variable dynamically.

```
Sub findCells()
Dim topCell As Integer
Dim left_Cell As Integer

Set refCell = Range(ActiveCell)

refCell.End(xlUp).Select
topCell = ActiveCell.Value
MsgBox topCell
refCell.End(xlToLeft).Select
leftCell = ActiveCell.Value
MsgBox leftCell

End Sub
```

Comment: use `Set refCell = ActiveCell` , and aslo define `Dim refCell As Range`

Comment: Are you trying to save the ActiveCell location or are you trying to save the value that the cell contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like the code below.
It's better if you stay away from `Select`, `ActiveCell`, and try to use qualified `Range`s as much as possible.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findCells()

Dim topCell As Long
Dim leftCell As Long
Dim refCell As Range

Set refCell = ActiveCell

topCell = refCell.End(xlUp).Value ' <-- gets the value of the top cell
topCell = refCell.End(xlUp).Row ' <-- gets the row number of the top cell
MsgBox topCell

leftCell = refCell.End(xlToLeft).Value ' <-- gets the value of the column to the left
leftCell = refCell.End(xlToLeft).Column ' <-- gets the column number of the column to the left    
MsgBox leftCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Accomplishes what I was trying to do, but much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to 30k, glad you didn't retire!